# Intersection form on quotient manifold

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, intersection-theory, 4-manifolds

Let $E_{1},E_{2}$ be elliptic curves over $\mathbb{C}$. We denote by $\iota_{i}$ the translation by a 2-torsion point on $E_{i}$. Then $G=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ acts freely on the the product $E_{1}\times E_{2}$ via the involution $\iota=(\iota_{1},\iota_{2})$. and the quotient 
$$
X=(E_{1}\times E_{2})/G
$$
is a 4-dimensional manifold (complex surface). I would like to understand the intersection form on the middle cohomology
$$
(-,-)_{X}:H^2(X,\mathbb{Z})\times H^2(X,\mathbb{Z}) \rightarrow H^4(X,\mathbb{Z})\cong \mathbb{Z}
$$
via the cup product. I initially thought

> There is a ono-to-one correspondence
>   between  $$ H^{2}(X,\mathbb{Z})
> > \longleftrightarrow H^{2}(E_{1}\times
> > E_{2},\mathbb{Z})^{G}, $$ Since the
>   action is free, the intersection form
>   on $H^{2}(X,\mathbb{Z})$ is given by
>   the intersection form on
>   $H^{2}(M\times N,\mathbb{Z})^{G}$
>   divided by $|G|$. So, any intersection
>   number on $H^{2}(M\times
> > N,\mathbb{Z})^{G}$ must be a multiple
>   of $|G|=2$.
>
> On the other hand, we have  $$
> > p_{1}^{*}(\alpha_{E_{1}}), \
> > p_{2}^{*}(\alpha_{E_{2}})\in
> > H^{2}(E_{1}\times
> > E_{2},\mathbb{Z})^{G} $$ (because $G$
>   preserves both $E_{1}$ and $E_{2}$)
>   and  $$ p_{1}^{*}(\alpha_{E_{1}})\cup
> > \
> > p_{2}^{*}(\alpha_{E_{2}})=\alpha_{E_{1}\times E_{2}} $$ where
>   $H^{\dim_{\mathbb{R}}(M)}(M,\mathbb{Z})\cong
> > \mathbb{Z}\alpha_{M}$ via the natural
>   orientation and $p_{i}$ is the $i$-th
>   projection of $E_{1}\times E_{2}$.
>   This means that the intersection
>   number $p_{1}^{*}(\alpha_{E_{1}})\cup \
> > p_{2}^{*}(\alpha_{E_{2}})$ is 1, not
>   divisible by $|G|=2$.

When I asked a [similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/179118/intersection-form-on-quotient-manifold), some people pointed out that the correspondence 
$$
H^{2}(X,\mathbb{Z}) \ \longleftrightarrow H^{2}(M\times N,\mathbb{Z})^{G},
$$
does not hold in general; there is the Hochschild-Serre spectral sequence
$$
E^{p,q}=H^{p}(G,H^{q}(E_{1}\times E_{2},\mathbb{Z}))\Rightarrow H^{p+q}(X,\mathbb{Z})
$$
Here $E^{0,2}$ term corresponds to $H^{2}(M\times N,\mathbb{Z})^{G}$ above.

Having said that, I still don't quite understand the intersection form on $X$ (mainly due to my poor understanding of the Spectral sequence). I would appreciate it if anyone could describe the intersection form. What if $\iota_{2}$ is replaced by $-id_{E_{2}}$?

Comment: If $\iota_2$ is replaced by $-id_{E_2}$ then $X$ is a hyperelliptic (also known as bielliptic) surface, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperelliptic_surface

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Luckily, the $X$ thus described is a torus. This means that $H^2(X,\mathbb Z)$ has a nice explicit description: It is $\wedge^2 H^1(X,\mathbb Z)$. The intersection form is the the symmetric bilinear map to $\wedge^4 H^1(X,\mathbb Z)=\mathbb Z$.  $H^1(X,\mathbb Z)$ is an index two sublattice of $H^1(E_1 \times E_2,\mathbb Z)$ , which I guess you can see from the exact sequence for homotopy groups of a fibration.

In fact, the action of $G$ on the cohomology groups is trivial, because it is homotopic to the identity, since the group of translations is connected!

So $H^2(X,\mathbb Z)$ lies in $H^2(E_1 \times E_2,\mathbb Z)$ and similarly $H^4(X,\mathbb Z)$ lies in $H^4(X,E_1 \times E_2)$, so you do indeed get a division by $|G|$ when you identify the $H^4$s with $\mathbb Z$. But this does not mean that all intersection forms in $H^2(E_1\times E_2,\mathbb Z)$ are even, just those for cocycles which are pullbacks of cocycles from $X$. The criterion for this is not $G$-invariance of the cohomology, as the $G$ action on the cohomology is trivial, it's $G$-invariance of the underlying cocycle.

Comment: Even if the action of $G$ on the cohomology groups is trivial, the group cohomology may be non-trivial, isn't it? You are essentially saying that the correspondence in my question is correct in this case, and also we don't have to divide the form by 2. 



Comment: What I have in my mind is an Enriques surface $S=T/\langle \iota \rangle$, where $T$ is a K3 surface and $\iota$ is an involution without fixed point. The intersection form $U\oplus E_{8}$ on $S$ is obtained as "half" of the invariant lattice $U(2)\oplus E_{8}(2)$ of the K3 surface $T$.

Comment: Michel -- to complement Will's answer: your $X$ is the quotient of the 4-torus $T=E_1\times E_2$ by a translation by some element $t$ of order 2.  The topological automorphism group of $T$ acts transitively on 2-torsion, so we may assume that $t$ lives in, say, $E_1$.

Comment: @Michel: I'm not sure which correspondence in your question you are referring to, because there are several.  And is the Enriques surface related to the elliptic curves in some way?

Comment: @Will I referred to the correspondence $H^{2}(X,\mathbb{Z})\leftrightarrow H^{2}(E_{1}\times E_{2},\mathbb{Z})^{G}$. Enriques surface is not relevant to my example. I just wanted to say that the intersection form on $X$ seems obtained by dividing that of $E_{1}\times E_{2}$ by $|G|$, just as the Enriques surface.

Comment: There is not a correspondence. There is actually an injection $H^2(X,\mathbb Z) \to H^2(E_1 \times E_2,\mathbb Z)^G=H^2(E_1\times E_2,\mathbb Z)$4. You do have to divide the form by $|G|$, in fact this is true in great generality. Let $f: Y \to X$ be a covering map of degree $n$ that is not necessarily the quotient by a group. If $A$ and $B$ are two cohomology cycles on $X$ whose degree adds to the real dimension of $X$, then $f^* A f^* B= n AB$.

Comment: This is simply because the set of intersections of the pullback of two manifolds is the pullback of the set of intersections, and the pullback of a set is $n$ times bigger!

Comment: I see. Then $p_{i}^{*}(\alpha_{E_{i}})$ in my question is not in the image of the injection $H^{2}(X,\mathbb{Z})\rightarrow H^{2}(E_{1}\times E_{2},\mathbb{Z})$ and thus the intersection $p_{1}^{*}(\alpha_{E_{1}})\cup p_{2}^{*}(\alpha_{E_{2}})$ is not divisible by $|G|$, I guess. 

Comment: Yes that's correct, because the cycle that represents it is not $G$-invariant.

Comment: Since $G$ acts on each $E_{i}$, it seems to me that $p_{i}^{*}(\alpha_{E_{i}})$ is $G$-invariant. Isn't $dz\wedge d\bar{z}$ (where $z$ is a coordinate of $E_{i}$) invariant under $G$?

Comment: The problem with using the forms is that that has no way of representing the integrality of the cohomology classes. You need to use dimension $2$ submanifolds to representing them. The submanifold representing that is a fiber of $p_{1}$, which is not $G$-invariant.

Comment: You are right. If we represent $p_{1}(\alpha_{E_{1}})$ as a fiber $p_{2}^{-1}(pt)$, then we need two fibers and thus $2p_{i}(\alpha_{E_{i}})=p_{2}^{-1}(pt)+p_{2}^{-1}(\iota_{2}(pt))$ is $G$-invariant. Then the intersection is number is divisible by $|G|$, as expected. But it seems strange to me that $p_{i}(\alpha_{E_{i}})$ is not $G$-invariant but $2p_{i}(\alpha_{E_{i}})$ is. Also, is the cohomology class $p_{i}(\alpha_{E_{1}})$ is sensible to $E_{2}$ part?

Comment: Well, it's not really about the class being $G$-invariant, it's about some cocycle in the appropriate cohomology theory being $g$-invariant. You can see why it has to be that way by looking at the $H^1$ of the circle under the degree $2$ map to itself. It's obvious from any number of arguments that the map on $H^1$ has to be multiplication by $2$, so only even classes lie in the image. I don't really know what "is sensible to $E_2$ part" means.

Comment: I don't quite understand $G$-invariant cocycles, but you example teaches us that we shouldn't invariant cohomology class; rather we should see the pullbacks and their intersections. If I understand correctly, there are $\beta_{E_{i}}\in H^{2}(X,\mathbb{Z})$ such that $\pi^{*}(\beta_{E_{i}})=2\alpha_{E_{i}}$ ($\pi$ is the quotient map) and $(\beta_{E_{1}},\beta_{E_{2}})=(2\alpha_{E_{1}},2\alpha_{E_{2}})/2=2$. What if we replace $\iota_{2}=-id_{E_{2}}$? The 2-dimensional manifold representing $\alpha_{E_{i}}$ is the same as before and the result seems identical. 

Comment: In that case $p_1^* \alpha_{E_1}$ and $p_2^* \alpha_{E_2}$ actually generate the cohomology group, I think. The reason is that the Euler characteristic is clearly $0$ but the rank of $H_1$ is only $2$ because it lives in the $G$-invariants of $H^1(E_1 \times E_1,\mathbb Z)$. Sp $H^3$ is rank $2$ and $H^2$ also has rank $2$.

Comment: I need to think about your comments to convince myself. Anyways, I really appreciate your details responses to my question. I have now much better understanding of my example. Thank you, Will ^_^